# Как реализовать докачку файла на сервер?

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, сокеты

Добрый день, подскажите как лучше реализовать докачку файла на сервер. Сервер принимает размер файла и имя (работаю через socket) ?

Comment: У клиента рассчитывается hash-сумма отправляемого файла (и сохраняется на сервере, например, дополнением к имени файла). Она, а не имя файла, является идентификатором файла, так как с одинаковым именем вслед может быть отправлен совершенно другой файл или этот же, но уже с изменениями. После разрыва связи hash вновь отправляется на сервер и производится по нему поиск. Если такой файла есть, то, соответственно, возвращается его размер. Далее передаете рассчитываете с какого смещения в файле начинать передачу данных.

Comment: В общем и целом докачка необходимо при реальных долговременных обрывах и отключениях. При кратковременных потерях соединения (а это может быть и минута и две) клиент и сервер все "решают" сами на уровне TCP протокола ориентируясь на выставленные сответствующие опции сокета.

Comment: @MaxZS, рассчитывать хэш по всему файлу, если он очень большой, может быть накладно. В этом случае лучше отправлять какой-нибудь UUID, который будет уникально идентифицировать каждый конкретный файл. Ну а то, является ли после обрыва файл тем же самым или же это закачка обновлённого, которому следует присвоить новый идентификатор, - пусть несёт ответственность клиент.

Comment: @alexis031182 Закачка большого файла тоже дело накладное. А алгоритмы расчета хэша бывают разные. Да. Какие-то будут быстрее и  будет вероятность коллизий. Но это грубая ошибка перекладывать ответственность на клиента. Всегда при работе с сетью считайте, что с другой стороны или хакер или дурак (да и не только с сетью).

Comment: @alexis031182 А примером того, что на пользователя нельзя возлагать ответственность может служить следующий алгоритм. Я закачиваю важный текстовый документ (даже будучи недокачанным он откроется, хотя это можно отнести и ко многим другим форматам). И тут вдруг вспоминаю, что забыл изменить одну важную цифру. Обрываю закачку. Меняю. Закачиваю опять. В итоге на сервере лежит старый документ. Те люди, кому этот документ был нужен/важен, выкачивают "старье". И получает все шишки от того, что документ не верен. Теряют по факту другие, а не клиент, который это закачал. Он уверен, что закачал новый.

Comment: @MaxZS, так если хэш рассчитывает клиент, то это также перекладывание на него ответственности. О чём тогда речь? Принципиально для сервера нет никакой разницы, что является ключом к файлу: хэш по содержимому или сгенерированный UUID. Просто второе будет всегда быстрее. Ваш пример с перезакачкой равнозначен для обоих типов ключей, просто нужно учитывать, что UUID, также как и хэш должен генерироваться новый, если в файле наличествуют изменения.

Comment: @alexis031182 По поводу первого момента (о перекладывании ответственности)... Вы действительно так думаете или специально так как бы невзначай подменили понятия клиента-пользователя и клиента-программы? Вроде и репутация не маленькая... А что касается времени изменения файла, то эта информация очень легко может потеряться даже порой при копировании. В общем и целом, если топикастеру интересно воспользоваться Вашими предложениями с подводными камнями, то это его право. Я же высказывал вариант с однозначным определением.

Comment: @MaxZS, вовсе не обязательно опускаться до фраз про репутацию. Наша с Вами дискуссия, надеюсь, не предполагает какой бы то ни было агрессивности. Что касаемо "подмены", почитайте собственные комментарии, в своих я "пользователя" не упоминал нигде. Время изменения файла я также никоим образом не оговаривал. В такой плачевной ситуации я бы не торопился быть столь категоричным. Разумеется, что автор вопроса воспользуется тем решением, что покажется ему наиболее оптимальным в т.ч. и по причине наличия тех нюансов, о которых мы можем не знать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно делать это так:
когда на сервер приходит запрос на закачку файла - проверять есть ли этот файл, если нету то записать соответствующую, уникальную строку пользователя, и на каждой порции отправленных байт записывать текущую позицию в файле.
если файл уже есть то отправлять клиенту позицию в файле + разрешение.
но лучше вариант с хешем, как уже писали выше